# MAGENTO Force customer to fulfill the address form again

Tags: php, magento, attributes, street-address

I created a new attribute to the address form and it is working fine, my problem is with older customers.
How can I make force them to have to edit their address?

WHen they go to the checkout page, they choose the old address without knowing about the new attribute, and it is really important for us that they fill it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

What I did to accomplish this was editing the billing.phtml directly under mage/sales/checkout/ and add some code to directly check if the new attribute exists for the address

using complete sql like:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_address_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = my_new_attribute_id AND entity_id = my_address_id
```

thanks,
Jonathan